# yams-cpp nested sequence returning map instead of value

Tags: c++, parsing, yaml-cpp

I am trying to parse the following config.yaml file.

`config.yaml`

```
foo:
  bar:
    baz: [1, 2, 3, 4]
    bam: "some_string_value"
```

`test.cpp`

```
YAML::Node configObj = YAML::LoadFile("cfig.yaml"); // loads file just fine

YAML::Node fooObj = configObj["foo"]; // this Node object is a Map

// iterate over foo node to get bar node
for( auto it = fooObj.begin(); it != fooObj.end(); ++it){
    YAML::Node barMap = it->second; // this Node object is a Map

    // iterate over bar node to get bad node
    for( auto i = barMap.begin(); i != barMap.end(); ++i){
        YAML::Node bazMap = i->second; // this node is a sequence

        for( std::size_t i=0; i<bazMap.size(); i++         
            auto index = bazMap[i].as<int>(); // <<< This is the problem
        }
    }
}
```

The problem as far as I can see is that I am expecting index to be an int but `bazMap[i].as<int>()` I am expecting to be 1 the first loop, 2 the second, etc.  What I am getting instead is `bazMap[i].as<int>()` is of type map.  What am I missing in my understanding here?

Thanks,

Bruce

**Update** The answer was that I stopped early in my nested for loops.

Comment: Did you solve this? If so, you can actually write an answer below and mark it "accepted".

Comment: Sorry, I was on vacation.  I did and I will.  Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The answer that I found rests in that I was unclear on what I was getting.

In the `config.yaml` file I was expecting the following:

```
foo.Type() == Map
bar.Type() == Sequence
baz.Type() == Sequence
```

but what I was getting was:

```
foo.Type() == Map
bar.Type() == Map
baz.Type() == Sequence
```

all I had to do to resolve this issue was to change the config file.

```
foo:
  bar:
    - baz: [1, 2, 3, 4]
    - bam: "some_string_value"
```

Then it parsed exactly as I had expected.

So the issue was the format of the config file and not in the parsing logic.